# Освободить память выделенную в С

Tags: c#, c++, dll

1. Есть некая библиотека DLL на C++ которая на запрос клиента в С# заполняет двухбайтовыми символами массив и возвращает адрес первого элемента, клиент C# в свою очередь копирует содержимое в свой буфер который потом уничтожается средствами C# (сборщик мусора).
2. вот привожу что есть

dll: file string_emplary.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "string_emplary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void FillArrayInt(int a[], int n)
{
    const char* b = &"Emplary"[0];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
}

wchar_t* Emplary (wchar_t dest[])
{
    /* Wide string literals have a leading L */
    const wchar_t* b = L"Emplary";
    /* This is the wide string version of strcpy */
    wcscpy(dest, b);
    /* This value must not be on the stack */
    return dest;
}
```

dll: file string_emplary.h:

```
    #pragma once
    #ifdef string_emplary
    #define string_emplary_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define string_emplary_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    
    extern "C" string_emplary_API void FillArrayInt(int a[], int n);
    extern "C" string_emplary_API wchar_t* Emplary(wchar_t dest[]);
```

Клиент C# file Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace import_from_cppdll
{
    public unsafe partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void FillArrayInt(int[] a, int n);
       
        
        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    
        public static extern char* Emplary(char[] incoming);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private unsafe void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int b = 8;
            int[] a = new int[8];
            FillArrayInt(a, b);
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                output += Convert.ToChar(a[i]); 
            }
                       
            var incoming = new char[8];          
            char* outBuf = Emplary(incoming);
            for (int i = 0; i < incoming.Length; i++)
            {
                incoming[i] = outBuf[i];
            }
            

        }
    }
}
```

3. Вот так все уничтожается в С# , нет утечек памяти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. На что мне было выдано замечание, что -цитата

> "Если память была выделена в C, ее необходимо освободить в C. C#
> ничего не знает о том, что вы сделали в C. Простой способ - сохранить
> память, выделенную в односвязном списке, и вызвать процедуру
> освобождения, когда вы закончите. Помните, что ваш C# небезопасен,
> т.е. управление памятью обрабатывается чем-то другим"

5. ***так собственно вопрос, как я понял мне необходимо вызвать процедуру
   освобождения памяти. как это все мне сделать?***

Comment: В упор не вижу выделения памяти в C...

Comment: Ключевое слово **Если**. А если память не выделяли, то и освобождать нечего. Ну а если все-таки выделяли, то освобождать надо способом, соответствующим тому, каким она была выделена.

Comment: То есть  функция`wchar_t* Emplary (wchar_t dest[])` ни чего сама не делает, а управляется клиентом C# который сам все чистит?

Comment: А где Вы видите в этой функции выделение памяти? Она получает на вход массив, заполняет его и возвращает. Все. Никаких выделений памяти нет (если, конечно, я не упускаю чего-то, что делается под капотом)

Comment: Функция написанная на с++возвращает указатель на участок памяти который сама заполнила, клиент C# пошел куда его послали, скопировал себе в локальный буфер все байты, и что все, освободил после этого?

Comment: Функции на с++ этот участок памяти не с потолка взяла, а получила от клиента на C# Выделяет память здесь клиент, а не функция на с++

Comment: то есть этот участок изначально под контролем у C# и будет освобожден. спасибо за пояснения